# Google Colab: How do I unpack a file that's uploaded on Google Drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tar, mount

I have a file that's stored on the `Bioinformatics project` folder of my google drive. I want to load and unpack this file `gbm_tcga_pub2013.tar.gz`.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

path='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Bioinformatics project'

!tar -xvzf path/gbm_tcga_pub2013.tar.gz
```

Traceback:

```
tar: path/gbm_tcga_pub2013.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 1):

`tar` is a bash command. `path` is a Python variable. There might be a way of mixing them, but this is not it. In this case, `tar` command is looking for `path/gbm_tcga_pub2013.tar.gz` directory, which obviously does not exist. The following should work:

```
!tar -xvzf /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Bioinformatics project/gbm_tcga_pub2013.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for readers in 2023:

When handling files in Google Drive using Google Colab you need to be aware of the following:

- Colab (notebooks) directly runs Python
- When you call a shell/bash command, you need to prefix it with "!", this opens a new shell and executes the commands there, afterward closes it.
- To pass Python variable values to the bash command you use the {myvar} syntax (newer syntax).
- In any case, file transfers between these are problematic and slow, especially for large files. Therefore use of shutil (Python) is preferred.
- When creating a tar.gz into the drive from VM, before closing the VM session, you need to flush it, closing the drive directly will cut the stream.

So the task can be done like this:

```py
drivepath = '/content/gdrive'

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(drivepath)

datapath = f'{drivepath}/MyDrive/mydatadir'
fn = 'expandme.tar.gz'
datafile = f'{datapath}/{fn}'

!tar -xvzf {datafile}
# or
!tar -xvzf {datapath}/expandme.tar.gz
# or
!tar -xvzf {drivepath}/MyDrive/mydatadir/expandme.tar.gz

...
```